# List - break into different PageBlockTables

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a list of data populated via SOQL, in this list I have a column `FinancialYear__c`. I'd like to generate a number of PageBlockTables based on groupings of the `FinancialYear__c` value.

```
e.g. PBT 1 = list of 13/14 data
     PBT 2 = list of 14/15 data etc etc
```

Im thinking a List of Lists and `apex:repeat` but not sure if this is the right approach/how to implement?

Here is the query:

```
List<Site__c> SupermarketList = [SELECT StoreNo__c
                                    , Probability__c
                                    , Name
                                    , JS_Region__c
                                    , JS_Zone__c
                                    , Address__c
                                    , Postcode__c
                                    , (SELECT MeetingDate__c
                                            , RecordType.name
                                            , Total_Sales_Area_Uplift__c
                                            , TU_Sales_Area_Uplift__c
                                            , TUSalesAreaPre__c
                                            , TUSalesAreaPost__c
                                            , SalesAreaPreExcCO__c
                                            , SalesAreaPostExcCO__c
                                            , NonFoodSalesAreaUplift__c
                                            , NonFoodSalesAreaPre__c
                                            , NonFoodSalesAreaPost__c
                                            , GMSalesAreaUplift__c
                                            , GMSalesAreaPre__c
                                            , GMSalesAreaPost__c
                                            , FoodSalesAreaUplift__c
                                            , FoodSalesAreaPre__c
                                            , FoodSalesAreaPost__c 
                                        FROM Financial__r 
                                            WHERE MeetingDate__c != null AND Recordtype.Name IN('CCM','CCM Update','IB')
                                            ORDER BY MeetingDate__c DESC
                                            LIMIT 1)
                                    , (SELECT Launch_date__c
                                            , Start_On_Site__c
                                            , Status__c
                                            , Store__c
                                            , ProjectName__c
                                            , Investment_Type__c
                                            , ProjectManager__c
                                            , MainContractor__c
                                            , RetailHandover__c
                                            , Closure__c
                                            , Launch_FY__c
                                            , Launch_Period__c
                                            , Launch_Quarter__c 
                                        FROM Investment_Programs__r 
                                            WHERE Status__c IN ('Live','Feasibility','Completed') AND RecordType.Name ='New Store' )
                                    FROM Site__c
                                    WHERE Recordtype.name = 'Supermarket'
                                        AND Probability__c IN('Open','Certain','Possible','Probable')
                                        AND Id IN (SELECT Site__c 
                                                    FROM Financial__c 
                                                    WHERE MeetingDate__c != null AND Recordtype.Name IN ('CCM','CCM Update','IB'))
                                        AND Id IN (SELECT Site__c
                                                    FROM InvestmentProgram__c 
                                                    WHERE Status__c IN ('Live','Feasibility','Completed') AND RecordType.Name ='New Store' ) 
                                    ORDER BY Launch_Date__c ASC 
                                    LIMIT 999];
```

I want a new `PageBlockTable` for every change in `Launch_FY__c`, I am assuming list of list is the way to just not sure how to populate a list of lists from a query like this?

Comment: Paul can you post the code you have, someone here would be able to help you better if they see through what you have implemented :)

Comment: You didn't post how you want to group column `FinancialYear__c` and why you need multiple PageBlockTables...

Comment: i need multiple tables as i want to use the footer to display summary info for each Financial Year. So a new table at every change in FinancialYear.

Comment: A query with two subqueries doesn't automatically, in my mind, lend itself to being a sequence of flat lists. Can you mock up what you're trying to do?

Comment: should have mentioned the subqueries only ever return one record, will put Limit 1 in anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to loop through the results in your controller and populate a map of lists (note I'm using a String for FY in this example but it should show the gist):

```
public Map<String, List<Object>> mapFYToList {get; private set;}

// in init or wherever:
mapFYToList = new Map<String, List<Object>>();

for(Result r : [query])
{
  if(mapFYToList.get(r.FY) == null)
  {
    mapFYToList.put(r.FY, new List<Object>{r]);
  }
  else
  {
    mapFYToList.get(r.FY).add(r);
  }
}
```

You'll probably want to get these years in order as well (and you could cache this result):

```
public List<String> GetFYKeys()
{
  List<String> keys = new List<String>();
  keys.addAll(mapFYToList.keySet());
  keys.sort();
  return keys;
}
```

Then in the page you can just loop over the map contents, doing a page block table for each list:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!keys}" var="fy">
  <apex:pageBlockDataTable value="{!mapFYToList[fy]}" var="obj">
    <apex:column value="{!obj.Name}"/>
    <!-- etc -->
  </apex:pageBLockDataTable>
</apex:repeat>
```

I've written all this straight in the editor so it could have a few syntax errors but hopefully the idea makes sense!

Comment: exactly what i needed

Comment: However run into a little issue displaying some of the data, previously had been using: `<apex:column value="{!obj.Investment_Programs__r[0].Status__c}"/>` But now i get the error: Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received Number Works fine for for data thats not coming from a subquery, any ideas?

Comment: Hi Paul, had to convert that to a comment since it's not an answer. Not sure why that's causing an issue... might be worth throwing `obj.InvestmentPrograms__r[0].Status__c` into a map using the `obj.Id` as the key, then you can just reference that map:   `{!statusMap[obj.Id]}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar on your page to:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myListOfList}" var="aList">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!aList}" var="anItem}">
    <apex:column>
      <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
      <apex:outputText value="{!anItem.Name}" />
    </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:repeat>
```